# Android VM crashes on Launch Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, kernel

I have a problem.
I've been working with Android in Eclipse for the past 4-5 weeks now and never had a problem with the VM (they were slow, yes. But never crashed).

Now, I believe since 4.2 when I started working on a new project for uni (deadline next week) my 4.2 VM suddently starts crashing on launch, because of "Kernel Panic" (resport at the end).

I wanted to ask if there is anything I could do, maybe download a hotfix or anything. Both the API and Eclipse are pretty much up to date or might there be something wrong with my computer?
(Somehow even my old VMs (2.3.3, 3.1 and 4.1) crash on launch 99% of the time)

Any advice would be highly appreciated. Here the beginning of the Crash-Log:

> Process:         emulator64-arm [1334] Path:
>   /Users/USER/*/emulator64-arm Identifier:      emulator64-arm Version: 
>   ??? Code Type:       X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:  eclipse [1156]
>   User ID:         501
>
> Date/Time:       2012-12-01 00:25:27.469 +0100 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.8.2 (12C2034) Report Version:  10
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          130686 sec Crashes Since Last
>   Report:           96 Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   32 Anonymous
>   UUID:                      ABE51F99-F7A9-2595-016E-C47FFD1F6C50
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
>
> VM Regions Near 0:
>   --> 
>       __TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100247000 [ 2332K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/*
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Do you have two screens? if yes, did you launch avd/vm on **secondary** screen last time?
If yes, then check config vm file at:

```
cd ~/.android/avd/  
ls -la   => here you see all avds
cd [your_vm.avd]
joe emulator-user.ini => edit this config file and see value
```

**window.x = 2054** - this is stupid value, cause says where to display emulator window. Value is set cause emulator window was displayed at second screen on x position 2054 but as I say it's bug at avd. Simply change it to better value to display window at your main screen so like my case:

```
window.x = 954
window.y = 199
uuid = 1342941165631
```

Save config file, start eclipse, start your avd/vm and all must run well.

Comment: Thank you :) That pretty much fixed it. I have an Android phone now anyways..no more VMs xD But thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Although the facepalm it caused was hazardous to my health.

Comment: I wanna hug you. This was driving me crazy.

Comment: Thanks! I started seeing this after installing the Intel HAXM so was convinced it was to do with that. I'd almost given up!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this happens when an external monitor is connected. Try disconnecting your external monitor and then start emulator. You can attach it back after the emulator starts.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Yesterday it worked fine. Today crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Then I noticed that the audio I was listening to stopped for half a second when launching the AVD. I though that might have something to do with it. I stopped iTunes I was listening to, restarted the AVD and yes success. No crash, it started up nicely.