# android emulator launch failed. emulator64-arm : BAD CPU Type in executable

Tags: android-emulator, launch

Yesterday I decided to start developing Android in my mac (Snow Leopard 10.6.8) 32-bit.
Everything was ok, i also imported my workspace which i worked in Linux for months. I open a project and compiles perfectly.

When i try to run the project it gives me this error :
 **"...android/sdk/tools/emulator64-arm : BAD CPU Type in executable"**

I am using eclipse juno for mobile developers and downloaded the latest android sdk for mac

It looks like a 32-bit 64-bit issue. But i couldnt solve it yet.

Anyone had the same issue ?

Comment: Maybe this thread can answer you

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654656/android-vm-crashes-on-launch-mac

Comment: Can refer to this - similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62236184/7680383

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I already found the problem.

Under the directory, android-sdk/tools/, i deleted every executable related to 64-bit system. Those files are :

emulator64-arm , emulator64-x86 etc.

Then relaunch the project and now it is working like a charm.

Hopefully this helps to anyone who suffers from the same issue.

Comment: I don't understand how could this could be the answer... It's not working and doesn't make sense as the answer for CPU-type problems.. Am I missing something?