# AVD Fails to Launch on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am running Eclipse June and Luna on Mac OSX 10.6.8. My AVD fails with following error message:

```
 Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_4_0_3_NEW'
 Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/Users/username/Desktop /android-sdk-macosx//tools/emulator": error=86, Bad CPU type in executable
```

I googled around found this is a 32 bit AVD error.  I deleted _64bit emulator files and run eclipse after reboot and try to load emulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776603/android-emulator-launch-failed-emulator64-arm-bad-cpu-type-in-executable did not work.