# Android MacOS dev: emulator64-crash-service quit unexpectedly. At wit's end

Tags: android, macos, cordova, crash

I have a macbook pro (Retina, 15 inch, late 2013) that is running High Sierra GM (17A365) and a fresh install and blank project in Android Studio always results in a crash (emulator64-crash-service quit unexpectedly.) when trying to run any android emulator. I have tried every suggestion I can find on the internet, NONE of them work. Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Since I have an external monitor connected to my mac, I tried both creating emulator-user.ini file with window.x values ([Android VM crashes on Launch Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654656/android-vm-crashes-on-launch-mac)) AND just tried disconnecting second monitor and running just on the macbook. Still crashes
2. Tried completely (including all prefs and hidden folders) uninstalling Android Studio, rebooting and reinstalling and setting up brand new default environment. Still crashes
3. Verified that HAXM is installed correctly and running loaded (kextstat | grep intel returns expected info), but have also tried without HAXM. Still crashes
4. Tried launching emulator from Terminal. Still crashes
5. Tried creating new avd from avd manager. All of them crash.
6. Tried changing settings in avd configs to use (or not use) Hardware/Software graphics, as well as fiddling with more or less memory than defaults. Still crashes.

Does anyone have anything left to try? I am pulling my hair out here. I would like to try my cordova app in Android, but it seems impossible from my mac.

Comment: i am having this problem.  i am going to try your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused it, but as a workaround creating a fresh account on my Mac and launching studio and emulator inside of that allows it to run. So it is something in my original account settings that is causing this crash, and I still don't have a clue what (although there are no active startup items, launch daemons, caches, saved app state, etc that I can find, I have cleared them all).